# Default dns server is loopback although the connection provide default servers

Tags: network, wifi, dns

I'm trying to understand where do I get the dns server configuration from.

As I understand, if the file /etc/resolve.conf contain no servers, so it fallback to servers that are defined by the physical connection (Wi-Fi)

once I removed all dns servers from /etc/resolve.conf, I got that my DNS is configured to the loopback address (127.0.0.1) instead of what the connection provides.

```
nslookup       
> server                              
Default server: 127.0.0.1                      
Address: 127.0.0.1#53
Default server: ::1                         
Address: ::1#53
```

and Here's the the default dns servers from the Wi-Fi connection:

[image]

Perhaps anyone can tell me why doesn't the default DNS server is selected to 10.196.X.X as provided by the connection (instead I get the loopback address)

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it, or flag for migration. 
[Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/) - https://superuser.com/questions/1744752/default-dns-server-is-set-to-loopback-although-the-physical-connection-provide-d